# Translating AT&T to INTEL syntax

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, att

I have found this GAS file that contains some bootloader code that can boot off of a CD and I would like to study it and try and make one of my own but the only problem is that it is in AT&T syntax not in Intel syntax and I know nothing about AT&T syntax, I have tried to use Intel2gas converter but it didn't convert it fully and then I tried to convert what it couldn't and the program turned out to be a mess.

Here is the Code that intel2gas output plus what I tried to fix:

```
;/* ISO-9660 boot sector
 ;* --------------------
 ;*
 ;* Copyright (c) 2008-2009 Frédéric Feret
 ;* All rights reserved.
 ;*
 ;* Features:
 ;*      - supports ISO-9660 filesystem ("El Torito")
 ;*      - supports multiples burning session
 ;*      - no floppy emulation
 ;*
 ;* Limitations:
 ;*      - supports only Joliet format
 ;*/
BITS  16
ORG 0x00

;/*
; * This is the main function of the boot sector, which loads the OS image
 ;* into memory at 1000:0000.
 ;*
 ;* Parameters:
 ;*      DL = boot disk number.
 ;*/
;MISMATCH: "        .global _start"
_start: 
        cli

 ;       /* The BIOS has loaded our boot sector at 0000:7C00. We move the code
  ;         of this boot sector at 9000:0000. */
        xor     ax,ax
        mov     ds,ax
        mov     si,07C00h                               /* DS:SI = 0000:7C00. */
        mov     ax,09000h
        mov     es,ax
        xor     di,di                                   /* ES:DI = 9000:0000. */
        mov     cx,00800h                               /* 2048 bytes. */
        rep movsb                                       /* do the relocation. */

        ;/* Jump to the new address. */
;MISMATCH: "        ljmp    $0x9000, $1f"

;.l1: 
 ;       /* Setup segment registers. */
        mov     ax,cs
        mov     ds,ax                                  ; /* DS = CS = 9000. */
        xor     ax,ax
        mov     es,ax
        mov     ss,ax                                   ;/* SS = ES = 0000. */
        mov     sp,07C00h                               ;/* SS:SP = 0000:7C00. */

       ; /* Save the boot disk number. */
        mov     [drive_number],dl

   ;     /* Clear the screen. */
        mov     ax,003h
        int     010h

        mov     si, msg_loading
        call    print_string

        sti

  ;      /* Check if the processor is a 386. */
        pushf
        pop     ax                                    ;  /* FLAGS -> AX */
        or      ax,03000h                              ; /* try to set IOPL bits. */
        push    ax
        popf                                            ;/* AX -> FLAGS */

        pushf
        pop     ax                                      ;/* FLAGS -> AX */
        test    ax,03000h                               ;/* check if IOPL bits are always set */
        jnz     short .l1                               ;/* it's a 386, or a higher model. */

        ;/* The processor is a 286 or even older model. We display an error message on the
         ;  screen and then prompts the user to press a key on the keyboard to restart 
          ; the computer. */
        mov     si, msg_no_386
        call    print_string
        jmp     reboot

.l1: 
        ;/* Get the size in bytes of a sector from the BIOS. Normally, the size of
         ;  a sector on a CD-ROM is 2048 bytes. */
        mov     word [disk_packet],01Ah
        mov     ah,048h
        xor     al,al
        mov     si, disk_packet
        mov     dl, [drive_number]
        int     013h
        jc      assume_2k_sector

        mov    ax, disk_packet + 0x18
        mov     [bytes_per_sect],ax
        jmp     .l1

assume_2k_sector: 
        ;/* An error occured while retrieving the size of a sector. We will display
         ;  a warning message on the screen, then we assume that a sector on the
          ; disk makes 2 kilobytes. */
        mov     word [bytes_per_sect],00800h
        mov     si, msg_assume_2k_sector
        call    print_string

.l1: 
        ;/* To load the OS image (which is located at the root directory of the disk),
         ;  we have to look at all sessions of the disk. We will retrieve information
          ; on the root directory (its size and location) of each session, load the
           ;directory into memory and see if the OS image filename is in this directory.
           ;If the file isn't found, we move on to the next session. If all sessions
           ;were covered and that the filename wasn't found, we conclude that the OS
           ;image isn't on the disk. The first volume descriptor is the 17th sector of
           ;the disk. */
        mov     eax,16

get_next_desc: 
        ;/* Read the sector in memory at 0000:1000. */
        mov     [desc_sector],eax
        mov     bx,01000h
        mov     cx,1
        call    read_sectors

        ;/* Check for the signature "\2CD001" at the beginning of the descriptor. */
        mov     si, cd_signature
        mov     di,01000h
        mov     cx,6
        cmpsb
        je      found_desc

        ;/* Check if we have looked in all the descriptors of volume. */
        cmp     byte [%es:0x1000],0FFh
        jne     next_desc

        ;/* We looked in all sessions of the disk, and the OS image wasn't found.
        ;   We display an error message on the screen and then prompts the user to
         ;  press a key to restart the computer. */
        mov     si, msg_file_not_found
        call    print_string
        jmp     reboot

next_desc: 
        ;/* Compute the next sector number to load. */
        mov     eax, [desc_sector]
        inc     eax
        jmp     get_next_desc

found_desc: 
        ;/* We have to load a volume descriptor of a session in memory. We will check
         ;  if the session supports the Joliet format for storing filenames and
          ; directories. Otherwise, the session is unknown. */
        mov     di,01058h
        mov     si, joliet_signature
        mov     cx,3
        cmps
        jne     next_desc

        ;/* We found a session that supports Joliet format. We can find the size and
         ;  the location of the root directory. */
        mov     eax, [es:0x109E]
        mov     [root_dir_start],eax
        mov     eax, [es:0x10A6]
        mov     [root_dir_size],eax

        ;/* Compute the number of sectors to load. */
        movzx   ebx,word [bytes_per_sect]
        div     ebx
        cmp     edx,0
        je      .l1
        inc     eax
.l1: 
        mov     [root_dir_sectors],ax

        ;/* Read the root directory in memory at 0000:1000. */
        mov     eax, [root_dir_start]
        mov     bx,01000h
        mov     cx, [root_dir_sectors]
        call    read_sectors

        ;/* We will look into the root directory the OS image filename. If the file has
         ;  been found, we save the sector number where that file ans its size in bytes.
          ; Otherwise, we move to the next session. */
        mov     di,01000h

search_file: 
        add     di,25

        ;/* Check if this entry refers to a file. */
        cmp     byte [es:+di],0
        jne     next_entry

        push    di
        add     di,8
        mov     si, osimage
        mov     cx,14
        cmps
        pop     di
        je      found_file                            ;  /* file found? */

next_entry: 
        add     di,7
        movzx   ax,byte [%es:+di]
        add     di,ax

.l1: 
        inc     di
        cmp     byte [es:+di],0
        je      1b

        ;/* Check if we have check all the entries of the root directory. */
        mov     eax, [root_dir_size]
        add     eax,01000h
        cmp     di,ax
        jb      search_file

        ;/* The OS image wasn't found in the root directory. We go to the next
         ;  session of the disk. */
        jmp     next_desc

found_file: 
        sub     di,25

        ;/* Get the location of this file. */
        mov     eax, [es:2+di]
        mov     [file_start],eax

        ;/* Get the size of this file. */
        mov     eax, [es:10+di]
        mov     [file_size],eax

        /* Compute the number of sectors to load. */
        movzx   ebx,word [bytes_per_sect]
        div     ebx
        cmp     edx,0
        je      .l1
        inc     eax
.l1: 
        mov     [file_sectors],ax

        ;/* Read the OS image in memory at 1000:0000. */
        mov     eax, [file_start]
        mov     bx,01000h
        mov     es,bx
        xor     bx,bx
        mov     cx, [file_sectors]
        call    read_sectors

        mov     dl, [drive_number]
        xor     si,si

        ;/* Run the OS loader... */
         ljmp    0x1000:0x0000

;/*
; * This function loads one or more sectors in memory.
; *
; * Parmaeters:
; *      EAX             first sector to load.
; *      CX              number of sectors to load.
; *      ES:BX           destination address.
; */
read_sectors: 
;        /* To request the BIOS to load the sectors, we need to build a data
 ;          packet that contains the number or sectors to load, the first
  ;         logical sector to load and destination address. The address of
   ;        this packet will then be given to the BIOS, which loads these 
    ;       sectors into memory. */
        mov     byte [disk_packet],010h

     ;   /* We don't read one single sector at a time. */
         mov disk_packet + 2, 0x01

       ; /* Write the destination address. */
         mov     disk_packet + 4, bx
         mov     disk_packet + 6, es

        ;/* Write the logical sector to load. */
        mov     disk_packet + 8, eax
        mov     disk_packet + 12, 0x0

read_one_sector: 
        ;/* Read the sector into memory. */
        mov     ah,042h
        xor     al,al
        mov     si, disk_packet
        mov     dl, [drive_number]
        int     013h;
        jnc     short .l1                               /* read error? */

        mov     si, msg_read_error
        call    print_string
        jmp     reboot

.l1: 
      ;  /* Updates the next sector to load. */
       inc    disk_packet + 8

       ; /* Updates the destination address. Rather than incrementing the offset, we
        ;   will increase the segment. */
        mov     ax, [bytes_per_sect]
        shr     ax,4
        add disk_packet + 6, ax
        loop    read_one_sector

        ret

;/* 
 ;* This function displays a string to the screen, at the current cursor
 ;* position.
 ;* 
 ;* Parameters:
 ;*      DS:SI           null-terminated string.
 ;*/
print_string: 
  ;      /* Read a character. */
        repe lodsb

   ;     /* Check if we reached the end of the string. */
        cmp     al,0
        je      short .l1

    ;    /* Displays the character on screen. */
        mov     ah,00Eh
        mov     bx,007h
        int     010h

        jmp     print_string

.l1: 
        ret

;/*
; * This function reboots the computer.
; */
reboot: 
        mov     si, msg_reboot
        call    print_string

 ;       /* Wait for a key. */
        xor     ax,ax
        int     016h

  ;      /* Rebooting... */
        int     019h

;/*
; * Messages
; */
msg_loading:            db     '\n\rLoading...\n\n\r', 0
msg_no_386:             db     'Error: 386 or higher processor required.\n\r', 0
msg_assume_2k_sector:   db     'Error: failed to get sector size, assume 2 Kb.\n\r', 0
msg_file_not_found:     db     'Error: OS image not found.\n\r', 0
msg_read_error:         db     'Error: cannot read on disk.\n\r', 0
msg_reboot:             db     'Press any key to restart your computer.\n\r', 0

;/*
; * Datas
; */
cd_signature:           db    002h
                        db     'CD001'
joliet_signature:       db    025h,02Fh,045h
MISMATCH: "osimage:                .byte 0, 'o', 0, 's', 0, 'i', 0, 'm', 0, 'a', 0, 'g', 0, 'e'"
drive_number:           db    0
bytes_per_sect:         dw    0
root_dir_size:          dd    0
root_dir_sectors:       dw    0
root_dir_start:         dd    0
file_size:              dd    0
file_sectors:           dw    0
file_start:             dd    0
desc_sector:            dd    0
disk_packet:            RESB   020h

;/*
 ;* Boot sector signature
 ;*/
ORG 2046

dw    0AA55h
```

Here are all the errors it is giving me when I try to assemble it

```
cdfs2.asm:34: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:37: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:38: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:39: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:47: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:50: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:51: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:67: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:68: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:70: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:73: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:74: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:75: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:133: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:197: error: symbol `cmps' redefined
cdfs2.asm:203: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:232: error: label or instruction expected at start of line
cdfs2.asm:253: error: parser: instruction expected
cdfs2.asm:289: error: expression syntax error
cdfs2.asm:363: error: parser: instruction expected
cdfs2.asm:378: error: program origin redefined
```

and This is what I use to assemble

```
nasm cdfs2.asm -o CD.iso
```

I have fixed it so it now assembles but it is now giving me an error When I try to load the ISO into virtual box that format is not supported My guess is because of what the Programmer stated above that

```
 ;* Limitations:
 ;*      - supports only Joliet format
```

Is there anyway to fix this? Here is the converted code:

```
;/* ISO-9660 boot sector
 ;* --------------------
 ;*
 ;* Copyright (c) 2008-2009 Frédéric Feret
 ;* All rights reserved.
 ;*
 ;* Features:
 ;*      - supports ISO-9660 filesystem ("El Torito")
 ;*      - supports multiples burning session
 ;*      - no floppy emulation
 ;*
 ;* Limitations:
 ;*      - supports only Joliet format
 ;*/
BITS  16
ORG 0x00

;/*
; * This is the main function of the boot sector, which loads the OS image
 ;* into memory at 1000:0000.
 ;*
 ;* Parameters:
 ;*      DL = boot disk number.
 ;*/
;MISMATCH: "        .global _start"
;_start: 
        cli

 ;       /* The BIOS has loaded our boot sector at 0000:7C00. We move the code
  ;         of this boot sector at 9000:0000. */
        xor     ax,ax
        mov     ds,ax
        mov     si,07C00h                        ; /* DS:SI = 0000:7C00. */
        mov     ax,09000h
        mov     es,ax
    xor     di,di                            ; /* ES:DI = 9000:0000. */
        mov     cx,00800h                        ; /* 2048 bytes. */
        rep movsb                                ; /* do the relocation. */

        ;/* Jump to the new address. */
;MISMATCH: "        ljmp    $0x9000, $1f"

    jmp 0x9000:here

here:

 ;       /* Setup segment registers. */
        mov     ax,cs
        mov     ds,ax                                  ; /* DS = CS = 9000. */
        xor     ax,ax
        mov     es,ax
        mov     ss,ax                                   ;/* SS = ES = 0000. */
        mov     sp,07C00h                               ;/* SS:SP = 0000:7C00. */

       ; /* Save the boot disk number. */
        mov     [drive_number],dl

   ;     /* Clear the screen. */
        mov     ax,003h
        int     010h

        mov     si, msg_loading
        call    print_string

        sti

  ;      /* Check if the processor is a 386. */
        pushf
        pop     ax                                    ;  /* FLAGS -> AX */
        or      ax,03000h                              ; /* try to set IOPL bits. */
        push    ax
        popf                                            ;/* AX -> FLAGS */

        pushf
        pop     ax                                      ;/* FLAGS -> AX */
        test    ax,03000h                               ;/* check if IOPL bits are always set */
        jnz     short .l1                               ;/* it's a 386, or a higher model. */

        ;/* The processor is a 286 or even older model. We display an error message on the
         ;  screen and then prompts the user to press a key on the keyboard to restart 
          ; the computer. */
        mov     si, msg_no_386
        call    print_string
        jmp     reboot

.l1: 
        ;/* Get the size in bytes of a sector from the BIOS. Normally, the size of
         ;  a sector on a CD-ROM is 2048 bytes. */
        mov     word [disk_packet],01Ah
        mov     ah,048h
        xor     al,al
        mov     si, disk_packet
        mov     dl, [drive_number]
        int     013h
        jc      assume_2k_sector

        mov    ax, disk_packet + 0x18
        mov     [bytes_per_sect],ax
        jmp     .l1

assume_2k_sector: 
        ;/* An error occured while retrieving the size of a sector. We will display
         ;  a warning message on the screen, then we assume that a sector on the
          ; disk makes 2 kilobytes. */
        mov     word [bytes_per_sect],00800h
        mov     si, msg_assume_2k_sector
        call    print_string

.l1: 
        ;/* To load the OS image (which is located at the root directory of the disk),
         ;  we have to look at all sessions of the disk. We will retrieve information
          ; on the root directory (its size and location) of each session, load the
           ;directory into memory and see if the OS image filename is in this directory.
           ;If the file isn't found, we move on to the next session. If all sessions
           ;were covered and that the filename wasn't found, we conclude that the OS
           ;image isn't on the disk. The first volume descriptor is the 17th sector of
           ;the disk. */
        mov     eax,16

get_next_desc: 
        ;/* Read the sector in memory at 0000:1000. */
        mov     [desc_sector],eax
        mov     bx,01000h
        mov     cx,1
        call    read_sectors

        ;/* Check for the signature "\2CD001" at the beginning of the descriptor. */
        mov     si, cd_signature
        mov     di,01000h
        mov     cx,6
        cmpsb
        je      found_desc

        ;/* Check if we have looked in all the descriptors of volume. */
        cmp     byte [es:0x1000],0FFh
        jne     next_desc

        ;/* We looked in all sessions of the disk, and the OS image wasn't found.
        ;   We display an error message on the screen and then prompts the user to
         ;  press a key to restart the computer. */
        mov     si, msg_file_not_found
        call    print_string
        jmp     reboot

next_desc: 
        ;/* Compute the next sector number to load. */
        mov     eax, [desc_sector]
        inc     eax
        jmp     get_next_desc

found_desc: 
        ;/* We have to load a volume descriptor of a session in memory. We will check
         ;  if the session supports the Joliet format for storing filenames and
          ; directories. Otherwise, the session is unknown. */
        mov     di,01058h
        mov     si, joliet_signature
        mov     cx,3
        cmpsb
        jne     next_desc

        ;/* We found a session that supports Joliet format. We can find the size and
         ;  the location of the root directory. */
        mov     eax, [es:0x109E]
        mov     [root_dir_start],eax
        mov     eax, [es:0x10A6]
        mov     [root_dir_size],eax

        ;/* Compute the number of sectors to load. */
        movzx   ebx,word [bytes_per_sect]
        div     ebx
        cmp     edx,0
        je      .l1
        inc     eax
.l1: 
        mov     [root_dir_sectors],ax

        ;/* Read the root directory in memory at 0000:1000. */
        mov     eax, [root_dir_start]
        mov     bx,01000h
        mov     cx, [root_dir_sectors]
        call    read_sectors

        ;/* We will look into the root directory the OS image filename. If the file has
         ;  been found, we save the sector number where that file ans its size in bytes.
          ; Otherwise, we move to the next session. */
        mov     di,01000h

search_file: 
        add     di,25

        ;/* Check if this entry refers to a file. */
        cmp     byte [es:+di],0
        jne     next_entry

        push    di
        add     di,8
        mov     si, osimage
        mov     cx,14
        cmpsb
        pop     di
        je      found_file                            ;  /* file found? */

next_entry: 
        add     di,7
        movzx   ax,byte [es:+di]
        add     di,ax

.l1: 
        inc     di
        cmp     byte [es:+di],0
        je      1b

        ;/* Check if we have check all the entries of the root directory. */
        mov     eax, [root_dir_size]
        add     eax,01000h
        cmp     di,ax
        jb      search_file

        ;/* The OS image wasn't found in the root directory. We go to the next
         ;  session of the disk. */
        jmp     next_desc

found_file: 
        sub     di,25

        ;/* Get the location of this file. */
        mov     eax, [es:2+di]
        mov     [file_start],eax

        ;/* Get the size of this file. */
        mov     eax, [es:10+di]
        mov     [file_size],eax

        ;/* Compute the number of sectors to load. */
        movzx   ebx,word [bytes_per_sect]
        div     ebx
        cmp     edx,0
        je      .l1
        inc     eax
.l1: 
        mov     [file_sectors],ax

        ;/* Read the OS image in memory at 1000:0000. */
        mov     eax, [file_start]
        mov     bx,01000h
        mov     es,bx
        xor     bx,bx
        mov     cx, [file_sectors]
        call    read_sectors

        mov     dl, [drive_number]
        xor     si,si

        ;/* Run the OS loader... */
        jmp    0x1000:0x0000

;/*
; * This function loads one or more sectors in memory.
; *
; * Parmaeters:
; *      EAX             first sector to load.
; *      CX              number of sectors to load.
; *      ES:BX           destination address.
; */
read_sectors: 
;        /* To request the BIOS to load the sectors, we need to build a data
 ;          packet that contains the number or sectors to load, the first
  ;         logical sector to load and destination address. The address of
   ;        this packet will then be given to the BIOS, which loads these 
    ;       sectors into memory. */
        mov     byte [disk_packet],010h

     ;   /* We don't read one single sector at a time. */
         mov [disk_packet + 2], word 0x01

       ; /* Write the destination address. */
         mov     [disk_packet + 4], bx
         mov     [disk_packet + 6], es

        ;/* Write the logical sector to load. */
        mov     [disk_packet + 8], eax
        mov     [disk_packet + 12], dword 0x0

read_one_sector: 
        ;/* Read the sector into memory. */
        mov     ah,042h
        xor     al,al
        mov     si, disk_packet
        mov     dl, [drive_number]
        int     013h
        jnc     short .l1                              ; /* read error? */

        mov     si, msg_read_error
        call    print_string
        jmp     reboot

.l1: 
      ;  /* Updates the next sector to load. */
       inc    dword [disk_packet + 8]

       ; /* Updates the destination address. Rather than incrementing the offset, we
        ;   will increase the segment. */
        mov     ax, [bytes_per_sect]
        shr     ax,4
        add [disk_packet + 6], ax
        loop    read_one_sector

        ret

;/* 
 ;* This function displays a string to the screen, at the current cursor
 ;* position.
 ;* 
 ;* Parameters:
 ;*      DS:SI           null-terminated string.
 ;*/
print_string: 
  ;      /* Read a character. */
        repe lodsb

   ;     /* Check if we reached the end of the string. */
        cmp     al,0
        je      short .l1

    ;    /* Displays the character on screen. */
        mov     ah,00Eh
        mov     bx,007h
        int     010h

        jmp     print_string

.l1: 
        ret

;/*
; * This function reboots the computer.
; */
reboot: 
        mov     si, msg_reboot
        call    print_string

 ;       /* Wait for a key. */
        xor     ax,ax
        int     016h

  ;      /* Rebooting... */
        int     019h

;/*
; * Messages
; */
msg_loading:            db     `\n\rLoading...\n\n\r`, 0
msg_no_386:             db     `Error: 386 or higher processor required.\n\r`, 0
msg_assume_2k_sector:   db     `Error: failed to get sector size, assume 2 Kb.\n\r`, 0
msg_file_not_found:     db     `Error: OS image not found.\n\r`, 0
msg_read_error:         db     `Error: cannot read on disk.\n\r`, 0
msg_reboot:             db     `Press any key to restart your computer.\n\r`, 0

;/*
; * Datas
; */
cd_signature:           db    002h
                        db     'CD001'
joliet_signature:       db    025h,02Fh,045h
osimage:                db    0, 'o', 0, 's', 0, 'i', 0, 'm', 0, 'a', 0, 'g', 0, 'e'
drive_number:           db    0
bytes_per_sect:         dw    0
root_dir_size:          dd    0
root_dir_sectors:       dw    0
root_dir_start:         dd    0
file_size:              dd    0
file_sectors:           dw    0
file_start:             dd    0
desc_sector:            dd    0
disk_packet:            times   020h db 0

;/*
 ;* Boot sector signature
 ;*/
; ORG 2046
times 2046 - ($ - $$) db 0


dw    0AA55h
```

Comment: So what is your Question? We will not convert it for you. Please ask what you don't understand and where `intel2gas` converter failed.

Comment: I just edited it to have the code that it output

Comment: @bkausbk My question is how would I go about fixing this or starting from scratch and Completely converting the Original

Comment: If you know Intel syntax, it'll take you perhaps an hour of study to understand the AT&T syntax. If you're working in the Linux space, you probably should get used to reading the AT&T syntax, even though it is an abomination.

Comment: @JimMischel Any rescources to help me study AT&T syntax?

Comment: @bkausbk Would you know how to go about fixing this?

Comment: @JimMischel Would you know hot to go about fixing this?

Comment: Offhand, no. I'm not familiar with that piece of software.

Comment: @AnonymousUser: You have to create a valid El Trotito image first. Please take a look at the specification http://download.intel.com/support/motherboards/desktop/sb/specscdrom.pdf

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> the only problem is that it is in AT&T syntax not in Intel syntax and I know nothing about AT&T syntax

Assuming that you have a decent grasp of Intel syntax x86 assembly, here's a brief summary of the most important differences in the AT&T syntax (taken from [here](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-ia/)):

**Register naming**

Register names are prefixed by `%`. That is, if `eax` has to be used, it should be used as `%eax`.

---

**Source and destination ordering**

In any instruction, source comes first and destination follows. This differs from Intel syntax, where source comes after destination.

`mov %eax, %ebx`, transfers the contents of `eax` to `ebx`.

---

**Size of operand**

The instructions are suffixed by `b`, `w`, or `l`, depending on whether the operand is a byte, word, or long. This is not mandatory; GCC tries provide the appropriate suffix by reading the operands. But specifying the suffixes manually improves the code readability and eliminates the possibility of the compilers guessing incorrectly.

```
movb %al, %bl -- Byte move
movw %ax, %bx -- Word move
movl %eax, %ebx -- Longword move
```

---

**Immediate operand**

An immediate operand is specified by using `$`.

```
movl $0xffff, %eax -- will move the value of 0xffff into eax register.
```

---

**Indirect memory reference**

Any indirect references to memory are done by using `( )`.

```
movb (%esi), %al -- will transfer the byte in the memory 
                    pointed by esi into al  register
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you provide the converted file including the error messages we can help.

> cdfs2.asm:232: error: label or instruction expected at start of line

It seems that the character ; is required if you want to use comments. This is missing here!

> cdfs2.asm:253: error: parser: instruction expected

There is no `ljmp` mnemonic, please take a look at the [Intel instruction set reference manual](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf). Mnemonics for unconditional jumps are `jmp`.

> cdfs2.asm:363: error: parser: instruction expected

Strings should be started with `db` like in

```
MISMATCH: db 'osimage:', 0, 'o', 0, 's', 0, 'i', 0, 'm', 0, 'a', 0, 'g', 0, 'e'
```

> cdfs2.asm:378: error: program origin redefined

Redefining origin with "ORG" seems not to be allowed.

> cdfs2.asm:197: error: symbol `cmps' redefined

Implicit form not allowed, should be

```
CMPS ES:[DI]
```

> cdfs2.asm:203: error: expression syntax error

Cpu registers ES, DS, AX, BX, CX, DX... doesn't have % prefixes like in AT&T syntax.

> cdfs2.asm:34: error: expression syntax error
>
> cdfs2.asm:37: error: expression syntax error
>
> cdfs2.asm:38: error: expression syntax error
>
> cdfs2.asm:39: error: expression syntax error

Comments should start with `;` character

These are some information that might help to detect similar errors.

Comment: "Implicit form not allowed, should be `CMPS ES:[DI]`" -- Actually it is `cmpsb` for NASM syntax, the "explicit" form is not allowed. The error was in removing the "b" suffix which is part of the instruction for NASM too.