# Mov instruction causing Expression Syntax Error

Tags: assembly, nasm, att

I am *very* new to assembly so please be nice.

I am trying to follow a tutorial to create a basic bootloader in assembly but have come across a hiccup. The following code should load the letter A into `%ax` and then trigger interrupt 10 but instead the `mov` and `int` instructions cause a syntax error. I'm pretty sure this code is valid so I really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction

```
# boot.asm
init:
    mov $0x0e41, %ax
    int $0x10
    hlt

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xaa55
```

The output from `nasm -f bin boot.asm -o boot.bin && qemu-system-x86_64 boot.bin` is:

```
boot.asm:2: error: expression syntax error
boot.asm:3: error: expression syntax error
```

Comment: The code is not in `nasm` syntax. It's at&t as used by the gnu assembler. For nasm which uses intel syntax you can do `mov ax, 0x0e41; int 0x10; hlt`.

Comment: @Jester Ah TYSM - I really need to get up to speed with these things

Comment: This would have been almost a duplicate of [Translating AT&T to INTEL syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24926280) I think, but the author of that question edited it after the answers were posted, making it a different question.

Comment: @PeterCordes If I knew what either of those things were I'm sure I'd have found that before :p - apologies

Comment: That wasn't a complaint directed at you, just looking for ways to officially mark this question as resolved without actually writing an answer.  (Although if your tutorial didn't include build commands for making a bootloader, look for a better tutorial; that's non-trivial and critical to get right.  And if you were trying to port your tutorial to a different assembler, yeah that's on you if you don't know asm yet.  Asm is very non-portable)  Anyway, there's probably an existing Q&A where the problem was trying to assemble a GAS source file with NASM, but I unfortunately didn't find it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness I will add an answer - credit to @Jester for actually pointing out the issue. The code is written using AT&T syntax however I tried to compile using nasm which uses Intel syntax.